# Solve "Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[stream.out]" in Camel

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, spring-rabbit

This is the class that I have written to read message from a queue

```
public class Sender {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes( new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/tasks?queue=learningqueue").to("stream:out");
            }
        } );
        camelContext.start();
    }
}
```

But when i run the above code I get following error. I have already added the camel-stream dependency.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[stream.out] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[rabbitmq://localhost:5672/tasks?queue=le... because of No endpoint could be found for: stream.out, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1071)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1008)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3397)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3128)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:182)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2957)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2953)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2976)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2953)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2920)
    at Learndata.camel.exam.sendrecv.Sender.main(Sender.java:16)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: stream.out, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:81)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:211)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:108)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:114)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:539)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:500)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:221)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1068)
    ... 12 more
```

This is my entire POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>camel.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>rabbitmq</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>ActiveMQ embedded with Camel</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Camel BOM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.2</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-stream -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
</dependency>

      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- the ActiveMQ client with connection pooling -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
      <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
      <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
      <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- the ActiveMQ broker is optional and can be removed if connecting to a remote broker only -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
      <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
      <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
      <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
      <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- allows the route to be ran via 'mvn camel:run' -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Since I have to use camel activemq I have put those dependencies also. Could that be the reason it's not working properly ?

Comment: Well...have you added the Camel stream component to your pom?

Comment: Yes I have included the camel stream dependency in the pom.

Comment: Also it is stream:out not, stream.out.

Comment: It's given as stream:out yet the same error.

Comment: Verify that your maven and code is correct. It works perfectly fine on my setup and please correct the question so that it is written as stream:out. The error is stating what the problem is. So rebuild your local repo and verify that you have written it correctly. Camel has a maven plugin to verify your route parameters.

Comment: I have corrected the question and also added the pom file. Let me check route parameters.

Comment: The dependency is required at runtime, how do you run your application?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDE to run the application.

Comment: Solved this issue using this example https://github.com/NitKrishNit/RabbitMQ-Camel-Spring.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what caused the error in the first place. I fixed the issue by creating the route with the help of an xml file. 
Here's what I have done :

**Bean class :**

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/Data/maven/Spring-Module.xml");
CamelContext rabbitMQContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(springContext, false);
rabbitMQContext.start();
```

**Spring-Module.xml :**

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
     <route>
            <from uri="rabbitmq://localhost:5672/tasks?queue=learningqueue">
            <to uri="stream:out"/>
        </route>
</camelContext>
```